# Algorithm for inverse of $X \cdot X^T$

Tags: matrices, algorithms, inverse, symmetric-matrices

Assume that matrix $A$ is defined as follows:

$A = X \cdot X^T$

Where $X$ is a Real matrix with more columns than rows, and $A$ has a matrix inverse.

One can find the inverse of $A$ defined as $A^{-1}$ using Gaussian Elimination, or LU Decomposition (find articles [here](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~kksivara/ma505/handouts/lu.pdf) and [here on pivoting](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~kksivara/ma505/handouts/lu-pivot.pdf)), but this has a complexity of $O(n^3)$.

Knowing that this matrix is symmetric and (I think?) [positive definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix), **is there a faster way to compute the exact inverse?**

---

*The background on the problem:*

For reference, I am trying to use this to quickly solve the following equation for $Z$:

$Z = Y X^T(X X^T)^{-1}X$

Where $X$ and $Y$ are known, and both are Real.

I am solving this in Python code, and I have not been able to find a package to calculate the inverse quickly as I am using exact rationals with the [`quicktions`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/quicktions) package.  [`sympy.Matrix.inv`](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.2/modules/matrices/matrices.html) is slower than just writing out code to do Gaussian Elimination.

I've seen this article [Don't invert that matrix](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/), but I don't know a way to solve this system without inverting a matrix.

Comment: Cholesky factorisation?

Comment: Is that the correct equation? It looks like it simplifies to $Z=Y$.

Comment: Yes, it is the correct equation.  It does not simplify to $Z=Y$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182662/inverse-of-symmetric-matrix-m-a-a-top